# Passing C# function to a DLL for callbacks

Tags: c#, vb6, pinvoke

I have some functions in a (stdcall) DLL that take a function pointer to perform a callback.

The methods `DeviceStateChangedNotify` and `CardDataStateChangedNotify` accept a `Long` parameter for the adress of the callback.

Here is a VB6 sample:

```
Declare Sub DeviceStateChangedNotify Lib "Device.dll" (ByVal lpFunc As Long)
Declare Sub CardDataStateChangedNotify Lib "Device.dll" (ByVal lpFunc As Long)

Public Sub SetupCallBacks()
     Call DeviceStateChangedNotify(AddressOf OnEventDeviceStateChanged)
     Call CardDataStateChangedNotify(AddressOf OnEventCardDataStateChanged)
End Sub

Public Sub OnEventDeviceStateChanged(ByVal parm As Long)
    ...
End Sub

Public Sub OnEventCardDataStateChanged(ByVal parm As Long)
    ...
End Sub
```

How can i do the equivalant of this in C#?

I've tried to create a delegate with the same method signature as `OnEventDeviceStateChanged` and `OnEventCardDataStateChanged` but doesn't seem to work:

```
delegate void DeviceStateChanged(long parm);
DeviceStateChanged stateChanged = EventDeviceStateChanged;
CardDataStateChangedNotify(stateChanged);
```

This produces a syntax error on the last line:

> Cannot convert from 'DeviceStateChanged' to 'long'

Comment: I would start by doing some research...

Comment: You can start out with automatic code converters; the languages are similar enough that a lot exist.  If you can't, or that doesn't work, then break it down into small pieces.  Go research how to create a method in C#, and how to create a class, and how to reference an external DLL, etc.  All of those individual tasks are well documented for C#.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code conversion service. You should try to figure out how to convert it yourself, and then post specific questions about actual problems you have doing so. Posting a block of code and saying "Convert this to another language" isn't acceptable here, and will most likely not be of use to future readers. Voting to close as too localized. Good luck.

Comment: The code is calling a custom API provided by some vendor, and registering some callbacks. Contact the vendor and ask them for C# P/Invoke declarations for the API calls.

Comment: My question is basically I do I convert a method/delegate into a long pointer.

Comment: Declare the parameters of `CardDataStateChangedNotify` and `DeviceStateChangedNotify` to be your delegate and the job is done. VB6 doesn't have function pointer/delegate types. Hence the use of `long` for those parmeters. But that's not what you want.

Comment: @Deanna Good work on your question edit, I approve!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, I was kinda' trying to convince the OP to write a more generic version :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close.

Yes, you need to create a delegate to match the callback function signature, and then change the DLL function declaration to use that delegate for the function pointer parameter. P/Invoke will then marshal this as required and pass a valid pointer to the function.

```
[DllImport("Device.dll")]
private static extern void DeviceStateChangedNotify(DeviceStateChangedDelegate Func);

private delegate void DeviceStateChangedDelegate(Int32 parm);

private void OnDeviceStateChanged(Int32 parm) {
  ...
}
```

When you need to pass it, just pass the function directly:

```
DeviceStateChangedNotify(OnDeviceStateChanged);
```

Note that as .NET applications are (by default) architecture agnostic (will run as 32-bit or 64-bit depending on the system architecture), you will need to ensure that your DLL and target architecture match.

If you just have a 32-bit DLL then you need to set your .NET project to target x86.

If you have 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs then you can leave the .NET project set to target any, but you'll need to check whether the DLL callback uses a 32-bit integer (C++ `DWORD`, etc) or a system integer (C++ `int`).
If it does use a system integer then you'll need to update your delegate and callback function to use `IntPtr` rather than `int` or `Int32`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the answer!  I was actually working on getting a magnetic card reader device to interface with an application I'm working on.   The vendor only provided a VB6 project that calls some Win32 DLLs to interface with their device.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your p/invoke code so that it receives a delegate rather than a `long`. In VB6 there is no way to specify delegates or even pointers and hence the use of integers and `AddressOf`.

The other issue is that VB6 `Long` is 32 bit so to match you need to use C# `int`. That's because C# `long` is 64 bit.

So, in C# you do it like this:

```
delegate void DeviceStateChanged(int parm);

[DllImport(@"Device.dll")]
static extern void DeviceStateChangedNotify(DeviceStateChanged lpFunc);

[DllImport(@"Device.dll")]
static extern void CardDataStateChangedNotify(DeviceStateChanged lpFunc);
```

And naturally you need to adapt your callback functions to match the new definition of the delegate.

And that's it!